# Mocking react custom hook with sinon stub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I have a custom hook with that returns api calls. It looks like this:

```
export const useApiData = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const [networkError, setNetworkError] = useState<string>(null);

    const getCase = (caseId: number) =>
        useQuery({
            queryKey: `case-${caseId}`,
            queryFn: (): Promise<AxiosResponse<CaseDto>> => CASE_API.api.getCase(caseId),
            staleTime: Infinity,
            suspense: true,
        });

    const api = {
        getCase,
    };

    return { api, networkError };
};
```

I would like to stub this custom hook with a sinon stub:

```
export function mockGetCase(sinonSandbox: SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox()) {
    const { api } = useApiData();
    sinonSandbox.stub(api, "getCase").callsFake(() => {
        return () => Promise.resolve(caseMockApiData);
    });

    return sinonSandbox;
}
```

But, this won't work since I am calling hook outside of react component:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug

How can I stub a custom react hook with sinon?

> and fix this problem.

I am using this hook like this in my components:

```
const { caseId } = useCase();
const { api } = useApiData();
const {
    data: { data: case },
} = api.getCase(caseId);
```

The CASE_API looks like this:

```
export const CASE_API: CaseApi<CaseDto> = useApi(
    new CaseApi({ baseURL: environment.url.case }),
    "case",
    "gcp"
);
```

And the hook `useApi` looks like this:

```
export function useApi<T extends AxiosClient>(api: T, app: string, cluster: string): T {
    api.instance.interceptors.request.use(
        async (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
            const secHeaders = await createDefaultHeaders(app, cluster);
            Object.assign(config.headers, secHeaders);

            return config;
        },
        function (error) {
            // error handling here
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );

    api.instance.interceptors.response.use(
        function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        function (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );

    return api;
}

const createDefaultHeaders = async (app: string, cluster: string) => {
    const idToken = await SecuritySessionUtils.getSecurityTokenForApp(app, cluster);
    const correlationId = SecuritySessionUtils.getCorrelationId();
    return {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + idToken,
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Correlation-ID": correlationId,
        "Call-Id": correlationId,
        "Consumer-Id": SecuritySessionUtils.getAppName(),
    };
};
```

I have tried to mock the api call by using mock service worker:

```
const server = setupServer(
    rest.get(`${environment.url.case}/api/case/:caseId`, (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.set("Content-Type", "application/json"), ctx.body(JSON.stringify(caseMockApiData)));
    })
);

before(() => {
    server.listen();
});
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
after(() => server.close());
```

But, then I get an error:

> TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
> at Function.getSecurityTokenForApp

`getSecurityTokenForApp` is a function that is called from useApi:

```
const createDefaultHeaders = async (app: string, cluster: string) => {
    const idToken = await SecuritySessionUtils.getSecurityTokenForApp(app, cluster);
```

And it looks like this:

```
static async getSecurityTokenForApp(app: string, cluster?: string) {
    const tokenReq = await fetch("/token", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ app, cluster }),
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
    });
    return await tokenReq.text();
}
```

Comment: It's number 2, you're breaking the rules of hooks. I could suggest another way to do it, but I have a feeling you're doing this imperatively because you don't know how to do it declaratively, which is the way react-query encourages you to do it. Can you share how you intend to use this hook? e.g. The component that uses this hook?

Comment: In case it wasn’t clear, you don’t want to know how you can stub it, you want to fix the incorrectly written hook

Comment: @AdamJenkins I have added to question how I am using this custom hook in my components.

Comment: Added an answer to help clarify how react query should be used in your component

Comment: For anybody coming across this question `useApi` is not actually a hook because it doesn't use any built-in react hooks or any other (real) custom hooks, despite the confusing fact that it's name begins with `use`. If it's name was `createApi` it would work just as well

Answer (score -2):

You should use the hook like this:

```
const { caseId } = useCase();
const { isLoading, isError, data, ...otherStuffFromReactQuery } = useApiData(caseId);
```

Here's the hook:

```
export const useApiData = (caseId: number) => {
    return useQuery({
            queryKey: `case-${caseId}`,
            queryFn: (): Promise<AxiosResponse<CaseDto>> => CASE_API.api.getCase(caseId),
            staleTime: Infinity,
            suspense: true,
    })
}
```

Comment: I added an example with just one api endpoint, because I wanted to exclude the irrelevant parts. Custom ```ùseApiData``` has many api endpoints, that is why I am returning them as properties of an object. Besides, that was not my question, I was wondering how can I stub such a custom hook?

Comment: @Leff - create hooks for each API endpoint. Your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you want to know how to stub the incorrectly written hook. The answer: write your hooks correctly, then stub what you need to stub in the correctly written ones.

Comment: How would you stub then the hook you written?

Comment: @Leff - fantastic question! I wouldn't stub it. I'd use [msw](https://mswjs.io/) to mock a network response and let axios/fetch/xhr/whatever do it's thing

Comment: I can't do that, I wanted to do it, but then I would have to stub some request interceptors that are adding security tokens to request header, since it is a microfrontend. So, I thought that it would be easier to stub a hook instead.

Comment: If you can't use `msw` to stub a network request, then stub `CASE_API.api.getCase` which is as close to the network as you can reasonably stub

Comment: You should also be using [@testing-library/react-hooks](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library), or something similar to test your hooks instead of calling them directly as if they were normal functions

Comment: That is where the problem is. CASE_API is calling another hook that does that job of intercepting and editing request header. So, I would have to stub that hook.

Comment: If `CASE_API` is calling another hook, then you're still doing react hooks wrong. I'd be happy to help you correct it if you post your CASE_API code. A hook is something that's tied __*directly*__ to a component instance. You can't call it as a normal function and expect it to **reliably** work.

Comment: @Leff - thanks for posting the code. `useAPI` is 100% not a hook because it involves no state, no effects and no other built-in hooks. It adds interceptors to an axios instance, that's all. It is indeed a normal function. You should remove the `use` from the name of it (if possible) to avoid confusion with real hooks

Comment: I have added code to the question. The useApi from CASE_API is a hook from a package that I am importing.

Comment: @Leff - you still don't have to stub the `useAPI` hook and can stub `CASE_API` directly if you want, because `useAPI` doesn't actually do anything of importance - it just adds interceptors and returns the same value. Personally, I'd still opt for using msw, but if you want to stub the return value for `getCase` on `CASE_API.api`, then that's the stub that will work for you in this specific test. But you still need to rewrite your `useApiData` hook

Comment: I have tried with using msw, but then it fails with ```TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported``` at the ```SecuritySessionUtils.getSecurityTokenForApp``` function which does a fetch call. I will add code to question.

Comment: @Leff - does anything in this issue help with that error message? https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/992

Comment: @Leff - alternatively, in a test environment, is your environment variable actually being defined (console.log it to find out) as an absolute URL?

Comment: it is, I can see that is logged, the problem is only in ```SecuritySessionUtils.getSecurityTokenForApp``` fetch call to ```token``` endpoint.

Comment: @Leff in that case check the github issue. While it might feel like you just want to stub the damn function and avoid this yak-shaving rabbit hole, doing it correctly (congrats on making it this far!) will reap you far better rewards. Keep going!

Comment: Final piece, just to remind, is that, because `useApi` is not really a hook, you can totally manually stub `CASE_API.case.getData` in your existing test without msw. So you've got an escape hatch if you can't figure out the `getSecurityTokenForApp` issue